# How to remove the property in Titan DB?

Tags: schema, titan, gremlin

```
 g.V(apple).properties("name").drop();
```

This is how i try to delete the property of apple vertex, but getting an error

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access element because its enclosing transaction is closed and unbound**

basically i'm trying to check that can we modify schema in TitanDB?
i go through the documentation but didn't get anything thing about that.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that you didn't properly iterate your `Traversal` responsible for creating that vertex.

From the Gremlin Console, using Titan v1.0.0 and TinkerPop v3.0.1:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> apple = g.addV().next()
==>v[4296]
gremlin> apple.property('name', 'Apple')
==>vp[name->Apple]
gremlin> apple.values()
==>Apple
gremlin> g.V(apple).properties('name').drop()
gremlin> apple.values()
gremlin>
```

Notice the call to `.next()` when creating the `apple` vertex.

Comment: how can i print properties, i'm using intellij

Comment: and how can i  delete propertykey

Answer (score 1):

The following example seems to work for me:

```
gremlin> produce = g.addVertex();
==>v[12]
gremlin> produce.values();
gremlin> produce.property("name", "apple");
==>vp[name->apple]
gremlin> produce.values();
apple
g.traversal().V(produce).properties("name").drop();
produce.values();
```

What are you doing before:

```
 g.V(apple).properties("name").drop();
```

The error you are getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access element because its enclosing transaction is closed and unbound

Is saying that the transaction is already closed which means that maybe you are **committing** or **closing** the graph. Either of those actions would close the transaction and make it unusable, so check your order of operations.

Comment: yeah i commit the transcation.

Comment: Committing always closes the transaction. Reopen your graph after committing and your property drop will work.

Comment: actually i'm using intellij and i didn't method addVertex method and though i find addV() method and also check i with gremlin console didn't work either

Comment: The example I produced is using `Titan-1` and `Tinkerpop-3` which has a very similar syntax in java. The premise is the same though. Commiting closes transactions, thus you need to reopen your graph.

Comment: gremlin> tx = graph.newTransaction();
==>standardtitantx[0x4b325930]

gremlin> produce = g.addVertex()

Getting this error 

No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource.addVertex() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: According to that error message your `g` is actually a `traversal` not a `graph` so you are incorrectly using `g`. I see that you created a new transaction with `tx = graph.newTransaction();` now you can just try `tx.addVertex()` that will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109118/discussion-between-mayur-raikwar-and-fido).

Comment: @Fido In the default Titan setup (see `scripts/empty-sample.groovy`), `g` is meant to be a `Traversal` and `graph` is meant to be a `Graph`. Also, `g = graph.traversal()` is expensive and should be a one-time operation at startup.